# Vaadin & Spring Boot, Reset/Refresh a Component

Tags: spring, vaadin

I have many layouts that extends VerticalLayout. I am removing all of them from a main layout add adding one of them to the main layout, to change the "page". First, is there a better option to this ?

My main question is, since I am adding the same component created in another scope, the content of the layouts doesn't change until I refresh. I want it to change after I click the icon in the menu bar.

So what I am looking for is a method like component.refresh() or something like this.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I would suggest you look at the Navigator class.

Comment: @Chris M Does navigator reset the components ?

Comment: If you get your VerticalLayouts to implement View, and register their classes with the navigator, it will create a new instance each time you navigate

Comment: are you doing this outside of a "request" (e.g. from a thread?).  in that case you would have to use polling/push to make that work.  but if you just remove/add components in reaction to a button click, that should need no refresh - that would change the state, that get's sent back to the client and rerender. maybe you could share some code?

Answer (score 0):

What your missing is this:
1. You can not add one component to two or more parents. The moment you add a component to parent2, its removed from parent1 (You get to see this when you hit refresh)
2. You are not using @PreserveOnRefresh on your UI class